# OCaml regex for date time

Tags: regex, date, time, ocaml

I made a regex to parse a date and time of format "DD-MM-YYYYhh:mm" but it seems to not work tho I don't get why. I got no error but it just doesn't accept any date and time I could pass to my program.

```
let checkDate d t =
    match Str.string_match (Str.regexp "\\([0][1-9]\\|[12][0-9]\\|3[0-1]\\)-\\([0][1-9]\\|1[0-2]\\)-\\(2[0-9]{3}\\)\\([0-1][0-9]\\|2[0-3]\\):\\([0-50-9]\\)") (d ^ t) 0 with
    | true  -> true
    | false -> false
in
```

What could I possibly did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{3}
```

is not a regexp construction in Str.

```
let checkDate d t =
  let dr = "\\(0[1-9]\\|[12][0-9]\\|3[0-1]\\)" in
  let mr = "\\([0][1-9]\\|1[0-2]\\)" in
  let yr = "\\(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)" in
  let hr = "\\([0-1][0-9]\\|2[0-3]\\):\\([0-50-9]\\)" in
  Str.string_match (Str.regexp (dr ^ "-" ^ mr ^ "-" ^ yr ^ hr)) (d ^ t) 0
```

This function works.

```
# checkDate "16-05-2017" "12:55";;
- : bool = true

# checkDate "16-05-2017" "12:65";;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works greatly! Just had to edit your "dr = "\\([0-2][0-9]\\|3[0-1]\\)" for my initial day regex because the 00 of a month doesn't exist :p

Comment: Hahaha, yes, I updated it ;-) By the way, I find it strange that your year is after 2000. ;-)

Comment: Well it's for a school project where we just have to create a log of train with their date and time of trip, we don't really know what would they count as correct date because sometime they really make weird test so we just considered that it can't be before 2000 xD

Comment: By the way, `match ... with true -> true | false -> false` is just disgusting. :D

Comment: Haha no worry I changed it